# Serializing to JSON

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, serialization

[this is my sql result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVwDx.png)

and i want to serialize the result to json 
like following

```
{
  "Studentid": 1000,
  "ExamType":[
  {
    "Examtype":"TERM 2",
    "ExamName":[{

        "ExamName":"PERIODIC TEST 1-Term2",
        "SubjectName": [{

               "SubjectName":"SL-MALAYALAM",
               "ComponentName":[{

                         "ComponenetName":"Exam",
                         "SubComponent":[{

                              "SubCOmponent":"Exam",
                              "ExamDate":"2017-08-03",
                              "MaxMark":"50.00",
                              "MarkObtained":"38.00",
                              "Grade":"B1"

                                        }]

                              },
                              {

                         "ComponenetName":"NOTEBOOK",
                         "SubComponent":[{

                              "SubCOmponent":"Neatness &  upkeep",
                              "ExamDate":"2017-08-03",
                              "MaxMark":"2.00",
                              "MarkObtained":"2.00" ,
                              "Grade":"A1"

                                        }]

                              }]

                        }]
            }]

  }]

}
```

how can i serialize the sql result to json in mvc api,i'm already using newtonsoft for serializing other results,using LINQ is better way? if yes how?

[my code Looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8h0X.png)

Comment: What is the problem you face with the Newtonsoft approach then? Share what you already have so we can go from there. What does your webapi method looks like? What does it return?

Comment: https://ibb.co/gYMOEm

Comment: Include your code in your question by [edit]-ing, a screenshot is not very searchable for future visitors.

Comment: I didn't mean to add a link to your screenshot.... Why is it  easier to make a screenshot, upload it to some external dodgy image sharing service, copy the url, paste it here, and linkify, instead of copy-ing your code, paste it in the posts, select everything and hit ctrl+k (if it was lacking four spaces in the first place)? I simply don't get it. If you want to be lazy then at least take the path with the least resistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any libraries that will do it for you automatically, but you can certainly write code that does something like:

```
        var grouped = results.GroupBy(r => r.StudentID).Select(g => new
        {
            StudentID = g.Key,
            ExamTypes = g.GroupBy(r => r.ExamType).Select(g2 => new
            {
                ExamType = g2.Key,
                ExamNames = g2.GroupBy(r => r.ExamName).Select(g3 => new
                {
                    ExamName = g3.Key,
                    SubjectNames = g3.GroupBy(r => r.SubjectName).Select(g4 => new
                    {
                        SubjectName = g4.Key,
                        SubComponents = g4.Select(r => new { SubjectComponentName = r.SubjectComponentName, ExamDate = r.ExamDate, MaxMark = r.MaxMark, MarkObtained = r.MarkObtained /* others here */ })
                    })
                })
            })
        });

        var serialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(grouped);
```

Note that I've pluralized the names of the properties whose values are collections, but if you're required to keep to the exact property names specified, you can change that easily enough.